# Is it possible to modify the visual studio callstack window context menu in an extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking to write a plugin for [Concord](https://github.com/microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/) that would allow me to filter some frames on the callstack that are mostly just noise.

I am hoping it's possible to make it configurable by adding a checkable option to this context menu:

[image: The visual studio callstack window right click context menu]

Comment: Hi Dan, so far, you can not add a menu button on Call Stack window and if my answer helps you handle this issue, you could accepting it and if not, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify the visual studio callstack window context
> menu in an extension?

**I think you cannot get it so far.**

If you want to add a button under menu of **Call Stack** Window, you should get its ID so that you can extend its menu and add any custom button.

But in [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-toolbars?view=vs-2017#tool-window-toolbars), Microsoft does not enumerate its GUID and ID value and they does not extend it to us.

However, **Output** window, **Properties** Window, **Error List** Window.....does.

So if you still want its value, you should suggest a feature request on [User Voiceforum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(suggest a feature) and they will consider your idea carefully and give you a satisfactory feedback.